# please solve this question on limits

Tags: limits

How can I calculate this limit?
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}e^{x}(\cos x)^{\sin^{-2}(x)}
$$

I have come across these types of problems in my exam...
please write any method to be followed to solve these type of questions.

Comment: My first instinct would be to take logs, try to evaluate the (hopefully) simpler resulting limit, then re-exponentiate

Comment: the easiest way to solve EVERY such problem is to take Taylor series up to $o(x^{2})$ (or some power of x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant $$\lim_{x \to 0} e^x \left ((\cos x)^{\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}}\right)$$
we have the following: since $\lim_{x \to 0} e^x = 1$, is suffices to solve: $$\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}$$
which is the same as: $$\lim_{x \to 0} e^{\frac{\ln\cos x}{\sin^2x}} $$
Using L'Hospital's rule (you didn't say I couldn't) on the exponent, we get: $$\lim_{x \to 0} e^{\frac{-\sin x}{2\sin x \cos^2 x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} e^{- \frac{1}{2\cos^2x}} = e^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you have meant $$\lim_{x\to0}e^x\cdot \{(\cos x)^{\dfrac1{\sin^2x}}\},$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}e^x\cdot \{(\cos x)^{\dfrac1{\sin^2x}}\} =\lim_{x\to0}e^x\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\{(\cos x)^{\dfrac1{\sin^2x}}\}$$

Now, $$\lim_{x\to0}(\cos x)^{\frac1{\sin^2x}}=[\lim_{x\to0}\{1+(\cos x-1)\}^{\dfrac1{\cos x-1}}]^{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x-1}{\sin^2x}}$$

Now for the inner limit, setting $\displaystyle\cos x-1=y$

$\displaystyle\implies\lim_{x\to0}\{1+(\cos x-1)\}^{\dfrac1{\cos x-1}}=\lim_{y\to0}(1+y)^{\dfrac1y}=e$

For the exponent,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x-1}{\sin^2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos^2 x-1}{\sin^2x(1+\cos x)}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem, $\lim_{x\to 0}e^{x}(cos x)^{\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}}$ falls in the realm of *Indeterminate Powers*. One of the requirement of Indeterminate Powers where $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is $f(x)$ approach $1$ and $f(x)$ approaches $\infty$ (In our case, $f(x) = \cos(x)$ and $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sin^2x}$). Thus we can apply the *L'Hospital Rule*.

Let $y = e^{x}(cos x)^{\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}}$,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}y = e^{x}(cos x)^{\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}}$$
Take the log of both sides,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\log(y) = \log(e^{x}(cos x)^{\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}})$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\log(y) = \log(e^{x}) + \log(cos x)^{\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\log(y) = x + {\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}\log(cos x)}$$

$$\log(y) = \lim_{x\to 0}x + \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}\log(cos x)}$$

$\lim_{x\to 0}x = 0$, Since $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1}{(sin x)^{2}}\log(cos x)}$, numerator and denominator both go to 0 as $x \rightarrow 0$, we can apply L'Hospital Rule,

$$\log(y) = 0 + \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{(\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)})}{\sin(2x)}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\log(y) = 0 - \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Thus, to get $\lim_{x\to 0} y$,

$$e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\log(y)} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} y = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$

Comment: Excuse me, but $lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(2x)\cos(x)}$ is most certainly not 0!

Comment: @Alqatrkapa right, I see that, I'll fix this immediately.

Comment: Also when you take the derivative of $\ln(\cos(x))$, you should obtain $-\sin(x)/\cos(x)$.

Comment: @cndu I have change the answer. I sincerely apologize to any inconvenience I may have caused. I thought I'm only working with $1/sin(x)$ as an exponent, when in fact it is squared.